# Django+Nginx gives 404 while serving static files

Tags: django, nginx, django-staticfiles

Whenever I load my site it gives me a 404 error while loading the images and css.

My nginx config:

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

root /usr/share/nginx/html;
index index.html index.htm;

client_max_body_size 4G;
server_name _;

keepalive_timeout 5;

# Your Django project's media files - amend as required
location /media  {
    alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media;
}

# your Django project's static files - amend as required
location /static/ {
    alias /home/django/django_project/csite/static/csite/;
    autoindex on;
}

# Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;

        proxy_pass http://app_server;
}

}
```

My `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "csite/static")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

You can view the directory structure [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pYs39J5MSk/)

My app name is `csite`.

Comment: Did you run `manage.py collectstatic`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
location /static/ {
    root /home/django/django_project/csite/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer according to my case, but you should find an answer to your issue. In my case, I have :

**My Django IP server : 172.30.10.92**

**My Nginx IP server : 172.30.10.93**

### 1- Install and Configure wsgi (located on Django server)

WSGI is a file created with your Django project.

The file is located in `/path/to/your/project/Myproject/wsgi.py`

We have to edit this file like this :

```
import os
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

import sys sys.path.append('/var/www/html/Myproject')
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "Myproject.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

### 2- Install and Configure gunicorn/supervisor (located on Django server)

In order to install gunicorn/supervisor, you have to execute in your shell :

```
pip install gunicorn
pip install supervisor
```

Then, you have to create a new file in `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/Myproject.conf` which looks like this :

```
[program:Myproject]
command = /home/valentin/.virtualenvs/MyprojectEnv/bin/gunicorn Myproject.wsgi:application --name "Myproject" --workers=4 --bind=0.0.0.0:8080 -- user="valentin" --group="valentin" ; Command to start app
user = username #You have to replace by your username
stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/supervisor.log
redirect_stderr = true
log
environment=LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8,LC_ALL=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

I specified **port 8080** which is the communication port between my application server and my web server.

### 3- Edit hosts file on nginx server (located on nginx server)

You have to edit your hosts file located to `/etc/hosts` and add a new entry to your Django server :

```
127.0.0.1 localhost 
127.0.1.1 valentin 
172.30.10.92 Myproject

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts ::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

### 4- New config file in nginx repository (located on nginx server)

This new file should be placed in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/Myproject.conf`

```
 server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name Myproject;

    root /var/www/html/Myproject/;

    location /static/ {
        root /var/www/html/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://172.30.10.92:8080;
        }       
}
```

The IP address corresponds to my Django server address. I specified the listen port (8080), the path to my Django project & static directory.

Then, you have to create a symbolic link to **sites-enabled**.

After ths operation, restart nginx service :

```
sudo service nginx restart
```

### 5- Allow nginx IP address in Django (located on Django server)

You have to edit your **settings.py** file in order to allow nginx IP address in **ALLOWED_HOSTS** :

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', '172.30.10.93', '127.0.0.1', '[::1]']
```

### 6- Finally execute gunicorn (located on Django server)

Finally, you have to start gunicorn. You should be inside your Django root project and execute :

```
gunicorn Myproject.wsgi:application --bind 172.30.10.92:8080
```

Now, in your browser, try to connect to your nginx server with the port :

```
http://172.30.10.93:8080
```

It works !

### EDIT

Your static directory haven't be placed in the same directory than your django project.
Create a new static directory, specify the path in your settings.py file and then, make `python manage.py collectstatic`.

Don't forget to edit your nginx files.